# Vibrations In Steering Wheel During Cold Weather

Tags: honda, vibration, acura, steering-wheel, tlx

Basically brand new car bought from the dealership with ~6000KM on it last week. They did a fresh oil change and helped me install winter tires for me. However when the vehicle starts up during cold weather, the steering wheel has a lot of vibrations and sometimes can be felt through the seats. The vibration stops after I drive the vehicle for around ~10mins.

Living in Canada, Alberta I find that as the weather for this week became warmer, I couldn't locate the vibrations anymore. Hopefully someone can help me identify the problem so I can enjoy a smoother ride. Thanks in advance

Vehicle: 2016 Acura TLX Tech 2.4L 4 Cylinder

edit: I know there should be a slight vibration, but the vibration in my tlx doesn't feel normal since I did a comparison to my old car which was a 09 TSX

Comment: How cold does it need to be to feel the vibrations?  I'm sure my definition of "cold" in Texas is quite a bit different than yours.  And you're basically saying that after the engine warms up, it goes away?

Comment: Currently its around 3 degrees  - 0 degrees and I can't feel the vibrations when I start up the vehicle. Around -5 degrees or colder is when I feel the vibrations in the steering wheel  and it would eventually go away after 10mins of driving

Comment: A vibrating steering wheel can be caused by warped brake discs(can happen by eg driving through water or snow with hot brakes), but then it should persist after everything is warmed up. Does it feel like it comes from the wheels, or the steering column/power steering? Are there any other influences, like, does it increase upon steering or speeding up or braking?

Comment: While I steer, speed up, and brake the vehicle's vibrations feel the same as when its in idle. The vibration just dies down after I drive the vehicle for a bit. The vibration feels like its coming from power steering? I'm not sure, I'm still a new driver and can't tell the difference if the vibration is  from the wheels or steering column/power steering.

Comment: Did you take it back to the dealer? Whatever is causing the vibration should be covered under warranty.

Answer (score 1):

Nylon tire cord and possible some polyester cords can do this. The tires are warm when you stop, they settle and develop flats on the bottom ( of course inflation pressure affects the amount). The next morning they are cold and stiff and retain the flat spot for a few minutes until the tire warms. Long ago , with more nylon cord tires this was very common.

Answer (score 0):

Probably normal fast idling that transitions to curb idle as the engine warms up. Due to the proximity of the steering rack and transmission the vibrations are felt in the steering wheel.